# How to determine if a number is an integer power?

Tags: logarithmic-scale

How can I do simple tests like determining if an integer is a power of 2?  Mathematically, the result below should be True, and I understand why it doesn't work on MMa, but how do I do this test properly so I'll get a correct result?

```
IntegerQ[Log[1024]/Log[2]]

False
```

Comment: Try `IntegerQ@ PowerExpand[ Log[1024]/Log[2] ]`

Comment: ResourceFunction["PerfectPowerQ"] will do this if you are not concerned about the base being 2.

Comment: Or `IntegerQ[Log[1024]/Log[2] // FullSimplify]`

Comment: Or `IntegerQ[Log2[1024]]`

Comment: Also `FractionalPart[Log[SetAccuracy[6^1000, 1]]/Log[6]] == 0` or ``Statistics`Library`RealIntegerQ[Log[SetAccuracy[6^1000, 1]]/Log[6]]`` will be fast for other bases.

Comment: `MatchQ[IntegerDigits[1024, 2], {1, 0 ...}]` also works.

Comment: The best answer for this particular kind of question is `IntegerQ@Log[2,1024]`.